# The networkd3 is displaying all data, not the subset I want to show based on widget inputs in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, networkd3, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to make a Shiny app where the user selects a few options and a network and data table will display based on the inputs. I have a diet study database and would like users to be able to specify the predator species they are interested in, the diet metric (weight, volumetric, etc) and the taxonomic level they want nodes identified to. The data table works fine (so I did not include the code) and updates based on the input but the network does not change, it only shows all of the data.  When I run the code for generating the plot outside of Shiny it works fine. This is my first shiny attempt so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)
library(networkD3)



 Diet <-data.frame(
  Predator_Scientific_Name = rep("Acanthocybium solanderi", 10),
  Class_Predator = rep("Actinopterygii", 10),
  Order_Predator = rep("Perciformes", 10),
  Family_Predator = rep("Scombridae", 10),
  Genus_Predator = rep("Acanthocybium", 10),
  Species_Predator = rep("solandri", 10),
  Class_Prey = rep("Actinopterygii", 10), 
  Order_Prey = c( "Clupeiformes" ,     NA ,  "Perciformes", "Perciformes",  "Perciformes", "Perciformes", "Perciformes", "Perciformes", "Tetraodontiformes", "Tetraodontiformes"),
  Family_Prey = c("Clupeidae", NA, "Coryphaenidae", "Carangidae", "Scombridae","Echeneidae","Carangidae", "Scombridae", "Balistidae","Diodontidae"),
  Genus_Prey = c("Sardinella", NA, "Coryphaena", "Decapterus", "Euthynnus",  NA, NA, NA, "Balistes", "Diodon"),
  Species_Prey = c("aurita" , "", "hippurus", "punctatus","alletteratus", "", "", "","capriscus", "spp."  ),
  Lowest_Taxonomic_Identification_Prey = c("Sardinella aurita","Actinopterygii","Coryphaena hippurus","Decapterus punctatus","Euthynnus alletteratus", "Echeneidae", "Carangidae","Scombridae","Balistes capriscus","Diodon spp."),
  Frequency_of_Occurrence = c(2.8, 59.1,  1.4,  7.0,  1.4,  1.4, 15.5, 21.1,  2.8,  4.2), StringAsFactors = FALSE
)

pred.name <- unique(Diet$Predator_Scientific_Name)
prey.tax <- unique(Diet$Lowest_Taxonomic_Identification_Prey)

#Progress bar function
compute_data <- function(updateProgress = NULL) {
  # Create 0-row data frame which will be used to store data
  dat <- data.frame(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0))

  for (i in 1:10) {
    Sys.sleep(0.25)

    # Compute new row of data
    new_row <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1), y = rnorm(1))

    # If we were passed a progress update function, call it
    if (is.function(updateProgress)) {
      text <- paste0("x:", round(new_row$x, 2), " y:", round(new_row$y, 2))
      updateProgress(detail = text)
    }

    # Add the new row of data
    dat <- rbind(dat, new_row)
  }

  dat
}
####

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "blue",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Diet Database"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Parameters",
               tabName = "paramaters",
               icon = shiny::icon("bar-chart")))
    ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "paramaters",
        fluidRow(
          shiny::column(
            width = 4,

            shinydashboard::box(
              title = "Predator",
              status = "primary",
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              collapsible = TRUE,
              width = NULL,
              shiny::helpText("Select a predator to view its connections and prey items:"),
              shiny::selectInput(
                "pred",
                shiny::h5("Predator Scientific Name:"),
                c(NA,pred.name))),

            shinydashboard::box(
                title = "Prey",
                status = "primary",
                solidHeader = TRUE,
                collapsible = TRUE,
                width = NULL,
                shiny::helpText("Select a prey taxa to view its connections and predators:"),
                shiny::selectInput(
                  "prey",
                  shiny::h5("Prey Taxa:"),
                  c(NA,prey.tax))),

            shinydashboard::box(
              title = "Diet Metric",
              status = "primary",
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              collapsible = TRUE,
              width = NULL,
              shiny::helpText("Select a diet metric to use:"),
              shiny::selectInput(
                "dietmetric",
                shiny::h5("Diet Metric:"),
                c("Frequency of Occurrence" = "Frequency_of_Occurrence",
                  "Wet Weight" = "Weight",
                  "Dry Weight" = "Dry_Weight",
                  "Volume" = "Volume",
                  "Index of Relative Importance" = "IRI",
                  "Index of Caloric Importance" = "ICI", 
                  "Number" = "Number"))),

             shinydashboard::box(
              title = "Taxonomic Level",
              status = "primary",
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              collapsible = TRUE,
              width = NULL,
              shiny::helpText("Select a taxonomic level of nodes:"),
              shiny::selectInput(
                "nodetax",
                shiny::h5("Taxonomic Level:"),
                c("Order" = "Order", 
                  "Family" = "Family",
                  "Genus" = "Genus",
                  "Species" = "Species"))),
            shinydashboard::box(
              title = "Generate Network",
              status = "primary",
              solidHeader = T,
              collapsible = T,
              width = NULL,
              actionButton("makenet", "Generate")
            )
      ),

      #Area for network to be displayed
      shiny::column(
        width = 8,
        shinydashboard::box(
          title = "Trophic Network",
          status = "primary",
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          collapsible = FALSE,
          width = NULL,
          forceNetworkOutput("netplot")
        )
      )
    ))


          )))




server <- function(input, output, session) {
   network.data <- eventReactive(input$makenet, { 
  edgelist <- Diet %>% filter(Predator_Scientific_Name == input$pred|Lowest_Taxonomic_Identification_Prey == input$prey 
  ) %>% select(
    paste(input$nodetax, "Predator", sep = "_"),
    Class_Predator,
    paste(input$nodetax, "Prey", sep = "_"),
    Class_Prey,
    input$dietmetric
  ) 

  colnames(edgelist) <- c("SourceName",
                          "SourceClass",
                          "TargetName",
                          "TargetClass",
                          "Weight")
  edgelist <- edgelist[complete.cases(edgelist),]
})

  output$netplot <- renderForceNetwork( {
  network.data()

  ig <-igraph::simplify(igraph::graph_from_data_frame(edgelist[,c(1,3,5)], directed = TRUE))

  SourceID <- TargetID <- c()
  for (i in 1:nrow(edgelist)) {
    SourceID[i] <- which(edgelist[i,1] == V(ig)$name)-1
    TargetID[i] <- which(edgelist[i,3] == V(ig)$name)-1
  }

  #Create edgelist that contains source and target nodes and edge weights

  edgeList <- cbind(edgelist, SourceID, TargetID)

  nodeList <- data.frame(ID = c(0:(igraph::vcount(ig) - 1)),
                         nName = igraph::V(ig)$name)

  #Determine and assign groups based on class
  preddf <-
    data.frame(SciName = edgelist[, 1], class = edgelist[, 2])
  preydf <-
    data.frame(SciName = edgelist[, 3], class = edgelist[, 4])
  groupsdf <- rbind(preddf, preydf)
  groupsdf <- groupsdf %>% mutate(SciName = as.character(SciName),
                                  class = as.character(class))
  nodeGroup <- c()
  for (i in 1:nrow(nodeList)) {
    index <- which(groupsdf[, 1] == nodeList$nName[i])
    nodeGroup[i] <- groupsdf[index[1], 2]
  }
  nodeList <-
    cbind(nodeList,
          nodeGroup)

    progress <- shiny::Progress$new()
    progress$set(message = "Generating your network...", value = 0)
    # Close the progress when this reactive exits (even if there's an error)
    on.exit(progress$close())

    # Create a callback function to update progress.
    # Each time this is called:
    # - If `value` is NULL, it will move the progress bar 1/5 of the remaining
    #   distance. If non-NULL, it will set the progress to that value.
    # - It also accepts optional detail text.
    updateProgress <- function(value = NULL, detail = NULL) {
      if (is.null(value)) {
        value <- progress$getValue()
        value <- value + (progress$getMax() - value) / 5
      }
      progress$set(value = value, detail = detail)
    }

    # Compute the new data, and pass in the updateProgress function so
    # that it can update the progress indicator.
    compute_data(updateProgress)

    networkD3::forceNetwork(
      Links = edgeList,
      # data frame that contains info about edges
      Nodes = nodeList,
      # data frame that contains info about nodes
      Source = "SourceID",
      # ID of source node
      Target = "TargetID",
      # ID of target node
      Value = "Weight",
      # value from the edge list (data frame) that will be used to value/weight relationship amongst nodes
      NodeID = "nName",
      # value from the node list (data frame) that contains node
      Group = "nodeGroup",
      # value from the node list (data frame) that contains value we want to use for node color
      fontSize = 25,
      opacity = 0.85,
      zoom = TRUE,
      # ability to zoom when click on the node
      opacityNoHover = 0.4 # opacity of labels when static
    )

  })


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you share your csv file? So that your example can be run on other people's system.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, you should check if in the final call to forceNetwork, is anything being reactively updated?

Comment: Also, you need to see what your network.data is storing.

Comment: Again a reproducible example will help a ton to solve your issue.

Comment: I updated my code to include the data structure. How can I check if the final call to forceNetwork if it is being reactively updated? I am still trying to get a handle on reactivity. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. It was not storing what I wanted it to in the network.data. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can share your solution as an answer as far as I know. It might help someone over the years.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing my fixed code in case it helps someone in the future. I basically just changed the top of the server code.

```
network.data <- eventReactive(input$makenet, { 
  Diet %>% filter(Predator_Scientific_Name == input$pred|Lowest_Taxonomic_Identification_Prey == input$prey 
  ) %>% select(
    paste(input$nodetax, "Predator", sep = "_"),
    Class_Predator,
    paste(input$nodetax, "Prey", sep = "_"),
    Class_Prey,
    input$dietmetric
  ) %>% rename("SourceName" = paste(input$nodetax, "Predator", sep = "_"),
                          "SourceClass" = Class_Predator,
                          "TargetName" = paste(input$nodetax, "Prey", sep = "_"),
                          "TargetClass" = Class_Prey,
                          "Weight" = input$dietmetric) %>% na.omit()

})

  output$netplot <- renderForceNetwork( {
  edgelist <- network.data()
```